# Error 404--Not Found From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have installed oracle forms 11g on my system. While running forms or reports, the browser shows the following error:

```
Error 404--Not Found
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found
```

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.
If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code `403 (Forbidden)` can be used instead. The `410 (Gone)` status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

How can I resolve this error?

Weblogic server is running well and i am able to access the admin console also.